# how to alter session in the sql query Oracle

Tags: oracle

i want to alter the session in oracle sql query. The main reason is to avoid the use of plsql in my java application.

is there any ways we can achieve this?

Comment: I don't see what altering the session has to do with avoiding stored procedures.

Comment: why would you want to achieve this(avoid plsql)? You want this as a rule enforcement in your dev department? PLSQL is organically linked with oracle sql(you may have a query like `select id, name, get_band(age) from emp`, which is sql but also plsql)

Comment: You want to prevent the use of PL/SQL by altering the session somehow; or you want to alter the session without using PL/SQL? Why would you need to use PL/SQL to alter the session? What exactly are you trying to do that has led you to this question?

Comment: Running alter session commands as part of your command is generally bad practice. What are you trying to achieve by altering the session?

Comment: Are you trying to set some session optimizer parameters?  You may be able to set some of them using the [OPT_PARAM](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABEBAID) hint.

Comment: Thanks @ Jon Heller  OPT_PARAM really helped. 

The query i was trying to use is

SELECT /*opt_param('_b_tree_bitmap_plans','false') */COUNT(*)
  FROM event e
  WHERE e.id_task     = 'xxxxxxx';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @ Jon Heller

Your OPT_PARAM idea really helped. The query i was trying to use is

```
SELECT /*+opt_param('_b_tree_bitmap_plans','false') */
  COUNT(1) 
FROM event e 
WHERE e.id_task = 'xxxxxxx';
```